# UIButton not appearing on viewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Hey Im trying to render a modal view on the ipad, like so.

```
login_manager *log = [[login_manager alloc]init];

UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:log];

nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

[self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];

[log release]`
```

Then adding a button to it in viewDidLoad.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

UIButton *facebook = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

facebook.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,402,68);

facebook.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loginFB.png"];

[facebook addTarget:self action:@selector(login_FB) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:facebook];}
```

However i cant get the button to appear on the screen, the image link is corrrect and viewDidLoad is being called, but nothing pops up. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(void)viewDidLoad

{

UIButton *facebook = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

facebook.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,402,68);

[facebook setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loginFB.png"] forState:UIControllStateNormal];

[facebook addTarget:self action:@selector(login_FB) 

forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:facebook];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{    
UIButton *sampleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[sampleButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 52)];
[sampleButton setTitle:@"Button Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sampleButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"loginFB.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sampleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:sampleButton];
}
```